# How can I make MacVim as "Application" on Mac;

Tags: macos, mac, vim

I would like to use [`Snap`](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/snap/id418073146?mt=12) (free) to assign a shortcut for Vim on Mac (installed as macvim through `brew` on command line). However, `Snap` only works when the application is literally "found as an application". 
Here's the window that `Snap` opens to find an "application"

[image: Window of Snap trying to find an application]

Is there a way to list the `Vim` (accessible through my Terminal as `mvim`) to be an application? Or, is there a way to call `Vim` with a keyboard shortcut, say <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install Platypus
https://github.com/sveinbjornt/Platypus#install

In Platypus create a script for you application and select an icon. I needed to fix the path to find brew installed applications

```
 #!/bin/sh
 export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
 gedit
```

You may need to play around with the interface type depending on the application

If you get `Apple can’t check app for malicious software error`

In the Finder on your Mac, locate the app you want to open.
Don’t use Launchpad to locate the app.
Control-click the app icon, then choose Open from the shortcut menu.
Click Open.
The app is saved as an exception to your security settings, and you can open it at any time by double-clicking it, just as you do with any registered app.

Source: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchleab3a043/mac

Comment: Great find. Glad to know about such "modern" tool :)

Answer (score 5):

Background: It suddenly came to me that Mac is not only a programming machine, but rather a graphical sandbox whose operation is supposed to be intuitive. (This is day 2 of my attempt to use a Mac, as a long-time Windows user.)

Solution is simple:

- Step 1: hold left-click on the (Mac)Vim symbol, and got to `Option` and then `Show in Finder`; this will bring us to where the executable file named as `MacVim` is located;
- Step 2: Create an "alias" for the `MacVim`-executable. This essentially creates a shortcut that opens a `MacVim` instance;
- Step 3: **DRAG** the "short cut" to the Application folder, found as the left-panel of the Finder.

Done.

PS: a failed attempt was to `Duplicate` the executable file, and drag it to the Application "folder" at the left panel of the finder; this ends up with essentially having two "installations" of Vim, of which will bring up two Vim icon if we open these two installations graphically. In short, `alias` and **DRAG**ing helps!

PPS: **Many thanks to RedBug**, for this helpful lesson on Automator. In return, I will select his answer as the *programmable* solution, yet keep my personal solution here, as a backup. (As of Fri Mar 18, 2016, 22:31, I am still looking forward to a modification of the AppleScript that will terminate the Terminal once having opened it to execute "mvim" command.)

Answer (score 1):

To launch MacVim from a shortcut.

Launch Automator and go to File > New and select « Services »

Select « no input » in the « Service receives » list.

In the search box at the upper right, search after « Run AppleScript ». Double click on it and enter this script:

```
on run {input}
    set cmd to "vim"
    tell application "System Events" to set terminalIsRunning to exists application process "Terminal"
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        if terminalIsRunning is true then
            do script with command cmd
        else
            do script with command cmd in window 1
        end if
    end tell
end run
```

Save your automator script.

Go in the « Keyboard shortcut pane » in System preferences.
Select service part.
Go to your new MacVim automator script and assign your Command+I shortcut.

Comment: Hi @Redbug, here is the thing: `Vim` does not show up in the list of "application". I followed your suggestion up till the "launch application" step, however, from the list I got from launch application, I did not find any of "macvim, vim or mvim". Any suggestion on this?

Comment: Try "launch a shell script" in place of "launch application" and put the full path of your mvim application

Comment: thank you for the timely update. I was able to find an "Action" called `Run Shell Script`, but feeding in `vim` ends up with a infinite loop (hitting run and the script keeps running); and feeding in `mvim`, which used to work on the terminal, was not recognized by the shell. \n In the list of available shells, I did not find an option for `terminal`. Should I install `vim` again for these different shells?

Comment: Ok.. My answer was modified with a solution that works with vim

Comment: Hi @Redbug, your code does the job of passing the string "vim" to the Terminal and have got it executed. However, there are two ripples: 1. that the Terminal only got used once, every new "call of the automator script" shall live me with a fresh new Terminal instance; 2. that upon quitting the MacVim session (I changed the string from "vim" to "mvim"), the Terminal is still there;  Thank you!

Comment: You might try eliminating all the lines between `on run {input}` and `end run`, and simply add the line `do shell script "vim"`. (Note: preferably you should use the full path to `vim` instead of just the command name).

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem (MacVim did not appear in the Applications directory). Tried what was suggested above but did not manage to make it work.
I chased the MacVim.app file until I found it (in my system) in /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.1-151

I duplicated the MacVim.app file, and put the copy in the Applications directory.

I now have 2 MacVims that work in my environment... but it is better than not being able to open some files with MacVim because it did not show up in the Applications directory.